# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str' when trying to compare a an array to a list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string

I`am trying to obtain a list containing a floating number and a string, a float and a string and so on (for example [0.13,"dog", 14.0, "cat",....])*
first of all is it possible to do?
secondly, I am using data from an array containing three column and 29 rows (coord_array) and a list of string (names)
the code I wrote is intended to create two list (maxcoord and mincoord) containing 6 element* as described above
the code i wrote is:

```
maxcoord = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
mincoord = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
for i in range(num_atoms):
    if(coord_array[i][0] > maxcoord[0]):
        maxcoord[0] = coord_array[i][0]
        maxcoord[1] = names[i]
    if(coord_array[i][0] < mincoord[0]):
        mincoord[0] = coord_array[i][0]
        mincoord[1] = names[i]
    if(coord_array[i][1] > maxcoord[2]):
        maxcoord[2] = coord_array[i][1]
        maxcoord[2] = names[i]
    if(coord_array[i][1] < mincoord[2]):
        mincoord[2] = coord_array[i][1]
        mincoord[2] = names[i]
    if(coord_array[i][2] > maxcoord[4]):
        maxcoord[4] = coord_array[i][2]
        maxcoord[5] = names[i]
    if(coord_array[i][2] < mincoord[4]):
        mincoord[4] = coord_array[i][2]
        mincoord[5] = names[i]
```

I already imported sys and numpy (as np)
and the output that I obtaine is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pract1_lesson", line 66, in <module>
    if(coord_array[i][1] > maxcoord[2]):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'
```

since `maxcoord[2]` should contain a 0 (zero), I don`t understand why it consider it as a "string" although there is an integer in that position.

how do I solve this problem? am I trying to do something impossible?
thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Show a complete piece of code we can run.  Yours is currently missing variables and we can't try it out.

Comment: Try casting the `maxcoord` array as a float/int, i.e. `maxcoord.as_type(int)`

Answer (score 0):

Your question incomplete. But based on the code :

```
if(coord_array[i][1] > maxcoord[2]):
        maxcoord[2] = coord_array[i][1]
        maxcoord[2] = names[i]
```

there are two consecutive assignments the the same "variable", which makes the first one totally useless. So I'm guessing this is one of those "typos".

Following the pattern in the other `if`s you probably meant to wright :

```
if(coord_array[i][1] > maxcoord[2]):
        maxcoord[2] = coord_array[i][1]
        maxcoord[3] = names[i]
```

And I'd like to point out that using heterogeneous lists, is confusing, and too painful to maintain. You de be better off storing a list containing instances of some class or dictionaries where each of them contains (a float and a str).

Comment: ok, I modified the mistake, and now, while for maxcoord I obtain the correct result, for mincoord it doesn`t work and live the list untouched (0,0,0,0,0,0). I am not doing as you suggested only because it took me a couple of hours just to write it this way hahah I must submit the project by Monday and I don`t want to lose time on changing that, I just have to make it works and print the result of coordmax e coordmin, and never reuse them again. so it`s not essential for me to make I efficient or more functional. thank you however for the suggestion and the help! :)